# How to solve this question on number theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algebraic-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

If $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$, show that $\frac {a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1} $ is the square of an integer provided that $a,b > 0$.

Comment: This is a famous problem, see the example section in this wiki page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

Comment: UGH HOW MANY TIMES IS THIS GOING TO BE ASKED (sorry)